# Rails 3: How to use original filename for an upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, uploadify, carrierwave

I'm following this tutorial to upload and encode videos: http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/video-encoding-with-uploadify-carrierwave-and-zencoder

I have the following line in my model:

```
Zencoder::Job.create({:input => "s3://mybucket/uploads/videos/#{model.id}/video.mp4"
```

I need to replace the "video.mp4" at the end of this line with the name of the file I upload. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: According to the tutorial, that shouldn't be in your model, but in your Uploader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CarrierWave's [SanitizedFile](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb) has an [`original_filename`](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb#L39) method you can use to access the original, unmodified name of the uploaded file.

```
Zencoder::Job.create({:input => "s3://mybucket/uploads/videos/#{model.id}/#{original_filename}"
```